# Angular reference ngIf to dynamic namined variable from ngFor

Tags: angular, binding

I want to access the input element in the following ngIf for checking if it's currently having a specific value or not. The not working part here is the code inside the `ngIf`.

```
<span *ngFor="let item of items;let i=index">
      <input type="text" #[InputItem+i] value="{{item}}"/>
      <div *ngIf="('InputItem'+i).value" >
        I'm focused!
      </div>
</span>
```

Comment: Access your input element inside your component.ts write a boolean method in it to validate your condition and use the method in your ngIf (always write your logic in the class not in the view it's better for binding and code readability)

Comment: @Maxime Gélinas , since it isn't business logic and more or less only reliable for showing a little hint to the user, I thought it would be supposed to be in the view so far.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mewimc?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: @yurzui That's the behaviour I wanted to have thanks.

Comment: @littleraspy Components are responsible to display so styling logic can go there (you will get better intellisense too). Business logic should go in your model in my opinion so you don't mix presentation and business logic. It's basically the MVC pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
<span *ngFor="let item of items;let i=index">
  <input type="text" value="{{item}}"/>
  <div *ngIf="InputItem[i]" >
    I'm focused!
  </div>
```

Declare variable
InputItem:[] as array

Try to declare InputItem as arry like InputItem[0] = false,InputItem[1] = false
like wise and you can update the variable when you need based condition